# Store a credit card with PayPal payment buttons

Tags: paypal, credit-card

Is there a way to integrate [/vault/credit-card call](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/) with [PayPal payment buttons](http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/)? I do not want to work with client credit card information but i can't find a way to redirect the client to paypal only to store his credit card information and for me to get his id on paypal to charge him than needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the PayPal/Payflow hosted checkout pages and process a 1.00 authorization.  Then store the transaction id on your system.  Then when you want to charge the buyer, you would just use the reference transaction API call to charge them.  You only need to pass over the amount you want to charge along with the previous successful transaction id, and PayPal will use the same credit card information that was used in the last transaction.

Comment: Caveat: this won't work with the PayPal payment buttons you mentioned however.